# How can i add a count up timer that resets when a cell is updated?

Tags: google-sheets, timer

In my spreadsheet, I have a column where each cell has a drop down menu. What I am trying to do, is whenever the value for a cell in that column is changed, I need a minute/second timer that is counting up to reset back to 0:00 and start counting up again in the same row. For example, if I change the drop down menu in C2, I need the timer at F2 to reset and start counting up. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a script to do that. Try this function in **Tools > Script editor**:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error('Please do not run the script in the script editor window. It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet.');
  }
  const columnToWatch = 3; // column C = 3
  const timerCellOffset = 10 - columnToWatch; // column J = 10
  const timerFormula = '=now() - value("<<NOW>>")';
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart !== columnToWatch
    || e.range.rowStart <= sheet.getFrozenRows()
    || !sheet.getName().match(/^(Dispatch Main|Sheet1|Sheet2|Sheet3)$/i)) {
    return;
  }
  const nowString = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), e.source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss');
  const formula = e.value
    ? timerFormula.replace('<<NOW>>', nowString)
    : '';
  e.range
    .offset(0, timerCellOffset, 1, 1)
    .setFormula(formula)
    .setNumberFormat('m:ss');
}
```

To run the function, modify a cell in Sheet1 column C. The counters will update every time the spreadsheet is modified. Choose **File > Spreadsheet settings > Calculation** to make it update every minute when the spreadsheet is open.

Google Sheets is not a real-time system, and there is no practical way of getting the counters to automatically update every *second*. To update the counters on-demand more easily, **Insert > Checkbox** in a free cell, and toggle the checkbox by pressing **Space**.

The function retrieves the spreadsheet's timezone because it needs to insert a static datetime value in a cell that is used to calculate the difference from `now()`, and these values must be in the same timezone to get the correct result.

Comment: I think I am understanding how to implement the script. I am not sure what formula to paste in or what changes would need to be made for it to work. I will need to have the timers in Column J. One for each Column C cell. To be safe, lets say 100 cells. So timer for change on C2 will be on J2, C3 edit to reset J3 timer etc.

I also see that you have a getTimeZone and other sheets listed. Time Zone will not matter as it should just be a minute second timer. Also I will only be using this on sheet1 which I have named Dispatch Main. Thanks in advance for any changes to get this working.

Comment: When I add script in the script editor, now I get: Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier line: 6 file: Untitled.gs when I try to save the project.

Comment: The error on line 6 happens when I delete all text before the copy/paste.I was getting no error on the original script.

Comment: It now giving me the timer. Thank you! I see that I can have it update every minute in Calculations. What do I need to do in Calculations so it will update every second?